# Predict function returns Fitted value even though I put newdata

Tags: r, validation

I'm making model validation testing function for my own.

In doing so, I let

```
 a=entire set of predictor variables in model-building set
 b=set of response variable in model-building set
 c=entire set of predictor variables in validation set
 d=set of response variable in validation set
 e=number of column which I have an interest
```

This is based on book Applied Linear Regression Models, Kutner , so I used 
    `library(ALSM)`.

In my case, model-building set is `SurgicalUnit`, and validation set is `SurgicalUnitAdditional`.

Both data consists of 10 columns, of which from 1st to 8th columns are entire set of indep. variables, 9th is the response variable, 10th is the log(response variable)

So, 
`a=SurgicalUnit[,1:8]; b=SurgicalUnit[,10]; 
c=SurgicalUnitAdditional[,1:8]; d=SurgicalUnitAdditional[,10]; e=c(1,2,3,8)`

, since I want to fit with logged response variable, and I want to regress with variable x1,x2,x3 and x8.

(Please note that the reason why I used "entire" set of independent variables with specific number of column instead of putting set of interested independent variables dircetly is, because I need to obtain Mallow's Cp in my function at once.)

So my regression is, `asdf=lm(b~as.matrix(a[e]))` , the problem is, I want to predict validation set in models built with model-building set. So, I let `preds=data.frame(c[e])` and finally `predict(asdf, newdata=preds)` which is equal with `predict(asdf)`, which means that it's fitted values of `asdf`.

Why predict doesn't work? Helps will be appreciated.

Below is my function

```
mod.valid=function(a,b,c,d,e){
asdf=lm(b~as.matrix(a[e]))              # model what you want
qwer=lm(b~as.matrix(a[1:max(e)]))       # full model in order to get Cp
mat=round(coef(summary(asdf))[,c(-3,-4)],4); mat2=matrix(0,5,2)
mat=rbind(mat,mat2); mat                  # matrix for coefficients and others(model-building)
n=nrow(anova(asdf)); m=nrow(anova(qwer))
nn=length(b)                                  # To get size of sample size
p=asdf$rank                                   # To get parameters p
cp=anova(asdf)$Sum[n] / (anova(qwer)$Mean[m]) - (nn-2*p); cp=round(cp,4)
mat[p+1,1]=p; mat[p+1,2]=cp             # adding p and Cp
rp=summary(asdf)$r.squared; rap=summary(asdf)$adj.r.squared; rp=round(rp,4); rap=round(rap,4)
mat[p+2,1]=rp; mat[p+2,2]=rap           # adding  Rp2 and Rap2
sse=anova(asdf)$Sum[n]; pre=MPV::PRESS(asdf); sse=round(sse,4); pre=round(pre,4)
mat[p+3,1]=sse; mat[p+3,2]=pre        # adding SSE and PRESS
**preds=data.frame(c[e]); predd=predict(asdf,newdata=preds)** **# I got problem here!**
mspr=sum((d-predd)^2) / length(d); mse=anova(asdf)$Mean[n]; mspr=round(mspr,4); mse=round(mse,4)
mat[p+4,1]=mse; mat[p+4,2]=mspr       # adding MSE and MSPR
aic=nn*log(anova(asdf)$Sum[n]) - nn*log(nn) + 2*p; aic=round(aic,4)
bic=nn*log(anova(asdf)$Sum[n]) - nn*log(nn) + log(nn)*p; bic=round(bic,4)
mat[p+5,1]=aic; mat[p+5,2]=bic        # adding AIC and BIC
rownames(mat)[p+1]="p&Cp"; rownames(mat)[p+2]="Rp.sq&Rap.sq"
rownames(mat)[p+3]="SSE&PRESS"; rownames(mat)[p+4]="MSE&MSPR"; rownames(mat)[p+5]="AIC&BIC"

asdf2=lm(d~as.matrix(c[e]))
qwer2=lm(d~as.matrix(c[1:max(e)]))
matt=round(coef(summary(asdf2))[,c(-3,-4)],4); matt2=matrix(0,5,2)
matt=rbind(matt,matt2); matt              # matrix for coefficients and others(validation)
n2=nrow(anova(asdf2)); m2=nrow(anova(qwer2))
nn2=length(d)                                    # To get size of sample size
p2=asdf$rank                                     # To get parameters p
cp2=anova(asdf2)$Sum[n2] / (anova(qwer2)$Mean[m2]) - (nn2-2*p2); cp2=round(cp2,4)
matt[p2+1,1]=p2; matt[p2+1,2]=cp2           # adding p and Cp
rp2=summary(asdf2)$r.squared; rap2=summary(asdf2)$adj.r.squared; rp2=round(rp2,4); rap2=round(rap2,4)
matt[p2+2,1]=rp2; matt[p2+2,2]=rap2     # adding  Rp2 and Rap2
sse2=anova(asdf2)$Sum[n]; pre2=MPV::PRESS(asdf2); sse2=round(sse2,4); pre2=round(pre2,4)
matt[p2+3,1]=sse2; matt[p2+3,2]=pre2      # adding SSE and PRESS
mse2=anova(asdf2)$Mean[n]; mse2=round(mse2,4)
matt[p2+4,1]=mse2; matt[p2+4,2]=NA        # adding MSE and MSPR, in this case MSPR=0
aic2=nn2*log(anova(asdf2)$Sum[n2]) - nn2*log(nn2) + 2*p2; aic2=round(aic2,4)
bic2=nn2*log(anova(asdf2)$Sum[n2]) - nn2*log(nn2) + log(nn2)*p2; bic2=round(bic2,4)
matt[p2+5,1]=aic2; matt[p2+5,2]=bic2      # adding AIC and BIC
mat=cbind(mat,matt); colnames(mat)=c("Estimate","Std.Error","Val.Estimate","Val.Std.Error")
print(mat)
```

}

This function will provide useful statistics for model validation.

It returns a matrix with coefficients, p, Mallow's Cp, R.squared, R.adj.squared, SSE, PRESS, MSE, MSPR, AIC and BIC.

Everythig works fine for general given data, except for **MSPR** since `predict` function doesn't work! It only returns the fitted.

Comment: Could it has to do with that you are using matrix, `as.matrix(a[e])` , to fit the model and data frame, `preds=data.frame(c[e])`, to test?

Comment: @DiscoSuperfly woo that's a reasonable guess, but `lm` function only accepts the matrix form, whereas `predict` function only accepts data.frame form. So I can't do anything...

Comment: No, `lm` does accept data frames.

Comment: I ran lm(b ~ data.frame(a[e])) which returns error,  how can I do..?

Comment: I could be wrong it my first comment. It seems as long as you have the same column names, it may not matter whether you are using matrix or data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this. You have to make sure the both training and test data has same column names.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x + rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y=y)
# model fitting
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data=df) 
predict(fit)

# creating new data
newx <- rnorm(50)
newdf <- data.frame(x = newx)
# making predictions
predict(fit, newdata = newdf)
```

Comment: As long as I'm doing multiple regression, I tried `df=data.frame(a=a,b=b) ` where `a=SurgicalUnit[,1:8]; b=SurgicalUnit[,10]` , `lm(df[9] ~ df[1:8], data=df)` doesn't even return the regression model, saying that it's not a type it wants..you can get this file from [link](http://people.stat.sc.edu/Hitchcock/stat701.html ) if you don't want to install `ALSM` packages, even though you have to download this if you want `SurgicalUnitAdditional`.

Comment: This `lm(df[9] ~ df[1:8], data=df)` isn't the way you should use it. In place of of `df[9]`, have its column name. Same goes for `df[1:8]`.

Comment: For example `lm(a ~.,  data = df)` where the first column of `df` is named `a`. All remaining columns are used as predictors.

Comment: df <- read.table("http://people.stat.sc.edu/Hitchcock/surgicalunitdata.txt")
fit <- lm(V10 ~., df)

Comment: # use only columns V1 and V2 as predictors for V10. Fit using top 40 sample 
fit_df <- df[1:40, ]
fit <- lm(V10 ~ V1 + V2, data = fit_df)

#predict
predict(fit, newdata=df[-c(1:40), ])

Comment: Ok, I got it. However, from the scratch, I need them to be general... So that I can take advantage of it with other data. lm(V10~V1+V2+...) cannot be used since I don't know how many variables I will use in future data. Still appreciate your effort!

Comment: "I need them to be general... " this doesn't make sense to me.  I thought you had no idea how to use formula or the `predict` function, and tried to explain. If you want to create different data frame in the future, then fitting `lm` using `~.` could be useful.

Comment: I tried not to bother you with my complicated R function, but maybe I need to fully explain what I have been doing so far. Please take a look.

Comment: @DiscorSuperfly Man I figured out. I thought it for an entire day, and the point was ' You have to make sure the both training and test data has same column names.' . And by using 'For example `lm(a ~., data = df)` where the first column of df is named a. All remaining columns are used as predictors. ' , I got what I want. Thank you very much!